# if statement skipping over options

Tags: python, if-statement

Whenever I run this code, no matter the input, it just skips to "Do you think you will make playoffs"

```
nflteam = input().capitalize

if nflteam in ["Browns"]:
  print("NICEEEEEE! If we don't win next week I'm gonna cry")
elif nflteam in ["Giants"]:
  print("I've been to a couple giants games!")
elif nflteam in ["Steelers"] or nflteam in ["Ravens"] or nflteam in ["Bengals"] or nflteam in ["Broncos"]:
  print("YOU SUCK!!!")
else:
  print("Do you think you will make playoffs? Yes or No?")
  nflyn = input().capitalize
  if nflyn in ["Yes"]:
    print("Good Luck!")
  elif nflyn in ["No"]:
    print("Hopefully you get a good draft pick!")
```

Comment: `str.capitalize` is a function, you need to call it via `capitalize()`

Comment: why not `if nflteam == "Browns"` and `elif nflteam in ["Steelers", "Ravens", "Bengals", "Broncos"]` ?

Answer (score 2):

You need to call capitalize function with (),
also you can get rid of ors if you put all elements in list , in compares with whole list. If you compare only one value you can use == operator instead of in [].

```
     nflteam = input().capitalize()
        if nflteam == "Browns":
          print("NICEEEEEE! If we don't win next week I'm gonna cry")
        elif nflteam in ["Giants"]:
          print("I've been to a couple giants games!")
        elif nflteam in ["Steelers","Ravens","Broncos","Bengals"]:
          print("YOU SUCK!!!")
        else:
          print("Do you think you will make playoffs? Yes or No?")
          nflyn = input().capitalize()
          if nflyn == "Yes":
            print("Good Luck!")
          elif nflyn == "No":
            print("Hopefully you get a good draft pick!")
```